# I need to display text with system generated value i.e alphanumeric value.So is it possible to create a stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 4 locations Chennai, Banglore, Hyderabad, Mumbai.

Depending on user selection from dropdown, I need to gennerate an id like this:

1. If they select Chennai - CHE001,CH002,CHE002,CHE003,CHE004.....etc
2. If they select Mumbai - MUM001,MUM002,MUM003,MUM004.......etc
3. If they select Hyderabad - HYD001,HYD002,HYD003,HYD004........etc like that in database it has to save

Like that auto generated id as has to save in database but it must be in unique.... I don't how it will work with SQL functions are stored procedure, asp.net .. please kindly help for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
declare @location varchar(50) = 'chennai'
declare @PreLocation varchar(6)
declare @Num int =45
SET @PreLocation = CASE WHEN(@location ='chennai') THEN 'CHE000' 
                    WHEN(@location ='banglore') THEN 'BAN000'
                    WHEN(@location ='hyderabad') THEN 'HYD000' 
                    WHEN(@location ='mumbai') THEN 'MUM000'END 

select right(LEFT(@PreLocation,6-Len(@Num)) + convert(varchar(5),@Num),6)
```